# Guice binding and FactoryModuleBuilder

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am a trying to use Guice (newbie here!!) for one of my projects.

so I have a

```
interface Consumer{    
}
```

and my implementations are

```
class XMLConsumer implements Consumer {
      XMLConsumer(DataQueue queue){
      }
}
```

I also have the DataQueue interface defined as

```
interface DataQueue {

}
```

and the implementation of DataQueue is as below

```
class FIFODataQueue implements DataQueue{
      ...
}
```

In my AppModule.configure method I have the below code

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure(){
      // Why do I need this ???
      bind(DataQueue.class).to(FIFODataQueue.class);

      // My factories are
      install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
      .implement(DataQueue.class, FIFODataQueue.class)
      .build(DataQueueFactory.class));

      install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
      .implement(Consumer.class, XMLConsumer.class)
      .build(ConsumerFactory.class));
    }
}
```

My ConsumerFactory is an interface with a create() method that returns a Consumer

My DataQueueFactory is an interface with a create() method that returns a DataQueue

In my main method I have

```
final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
ConsumerFactory consFactory = injector.getInstance(ConsumerFactory.class);
Consumer cons = consFactory.create();
```

So my question is

1. I don't explicity create the DataQueue as I expect Guice to do this for me. Is this correct??
2. I seem to need the bind statement

   bind(DataQueue.class).to(FIFODataQueue.class);

but why do I need this. I am specifying in my install the same information isn't it by saying

```
.implement(DataQueue.class, FIFODataQueue.class)
```

or is my understanding wrong in this case?
If I don't specify the bind statement I get a instance not bound exception while Guice tries to autowire the objects.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you code is more or less complete, you are overdoing things with FactoryModuleBuilder. FactoryModuleBuilder is for when you can't inject all parameters for creating an object. They are not used for injecting the object directly, they are used for injecting a factory. `ConsumerFactory` is not using the factory for creating a `DataQueue`, it uses the explicit binding (that's why you need it).

Where you go wrong is in the definition of `XMLConsumer`. The Constructor Guice should use must be annotated with `@Inject`.

Then you can just ask your Injector for a `Consumer`.